# For Shuttle SRB solid fuel perforations, what is the shape of the double-truncated-cone?

Tags: solid-fuel, srb

[image: New image with Cross Sections]I understand the 11-point star perforations in the solid fuel in the top-most SRB section. Several articles say that the remaining sections had a double-truncated-cone perforation.

[image: Double-Truncated-Cone?]

Is my illustration correct for that shape-name? If it is, was there one of these per SRB fuel section? Were the top and bottom of the illustration the top and bottom of each fuel section?

I would have thought that they would have been simple right-circular cylinders, since that would be their shape as they were burning. Can someone enlighten me on this? It's merely out of interest since there is the whole discussion of the 11-point star perforation for the first section to give the rockets the most thrust at lift-off.

Answer (score 4):

These schematics from the [Press Reference Manual](https://archive.org/details/PressInformationSpaceShuttleTransportationSystemMarch1982/page/n66/mode/1up?view=theater) and [Space Shuttle Systems Handbook](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/JSC-11174%20-%20Space_Shuttle_Systems_Handbook_Vol2.pdf) show a side view of the shuttle solid rocket booster motor grain shape.

The void in the motor doesn't "neck down" as in your sketch, it opens up continuously until it reaches the nozzle.

A [1990 Thiokol document](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/TWR-50068%20-%20Thiokol%20SRB%20Space%20Shuttle%20Flight%20Support%20Motor%20No%201%20Final%20Test%20Report%2019910006751.pdf) describes the grain thusly:

> The propellant grain design consisted of an 11-point star with a
> smooth bore-to-fin cavity transition region that tapered into a center
> perforated (CP) configuration in the forward segment (Drawing No.
> 1U77186). The two center segments (Drawing No. 1U77190) were
> double-tapered CP configurations and the aft segment (Drawing No.
> 1U76676) was a triple-taper CP configuration with a cutout for the
> partially submerged nozzle.

[image: Press Manual SRB Schematic]

[image: SSSH Schematic]

This snippet from the Systems Handbook drawing shows the star grain at the right (section A-A in the diagram just above) and at the left, shows a view looking up the motor.

[image: view looking up the pipe]

Comment: I suspect the image is out dated... many booster images and video of grain pouring show a constant ID cylinder for mid sections and star at bottom. I've not seen any that show star section at tip if booster.  Of course, I'm open to learning that I'm mistaken.

Comment: You don't think the forward segments had a star grain? I'm away from my good references.

Comment: the 1982 "press manual" says I'm wrong.    On page 60 " The propellant is an 11-point star-shaped perforation in the forward motor segment and a double-truncated-cone perforation in each of the aft segments and aft closure. This configuration provides high thrust at ignition, then reduces the thrust by approximately a third 50 seconds after liftoff to prevent overstressing of the vehicle during maximum dynamic pressure (max q)."      SO... "perforations" is a correct term and it appears (so far) that my understanding of which combustion surface shapes are located where may be really flawed.

Comment: I found a 1990 Thiokol document saying basically what you just said, and edited that in.

Comment: my "pulled from somewhere" response is completely wrong and so I've deleted.   The 1990 test report from joint redesign is very interesting.  THANKS for the education.

Comment: I'm trying to get the definitive document but it is a sloooow download here

Comment: I ran across other sources, though not necessarily credible, that talked about these 2 types of perforations. The diagrams above talk about ‘grain’, but show that as star-shaped for 1st segment and then smooth bore for the other segments. This is my first encounter with solid rockets. What is the difference between ‘perforations’ and ‘grain’ since the diagrams do not mention ‘perforations’ or ‘double-truncated-cone’?

Comment: @DaveS the "propellant grain" is just the part of the solid motor that burns up. The "perforations" are the holes in the grain that control the burning rate. The double cone is at the very front of the grain - in side view it's a long thin triangle that flares out into a wider angle - those are the two cones. https://imgur.com/ZraJUt6 It looks like a funnel, not like a football as in your sketch.

Comment: I'll add in another picture.

Comment: From 2 of the latter illustrations, I did a little photo editing and created what I would conceive as new cross sections: BB, CC, and DD, pictured below. The Thiokol document referenced above says, “The propellant grain design consisted of an 11-point star with a smooth bore-to-fin cavity transition region that tapered into a center perforated (CP) configuration in the forward segment (Drawing No. 1U77186)….” I am assuming that the bore-to-fin cavity would enlarge as shown in my illustrations of the cross sections and in the 3 truncated cone shapes in the forward segment and below.

Comment: Can I also make an assumption that the thrust level would drop at the start of the second cone, as part of the Max-Q throttle back with the SSMEs? A follow-on assumption would be that at the start of the third cone the SRB thrust would increase as would that of the SSMEs post the Max-Q region. The transitions between these cones would be planned by Thiocol to align SRB thrust levels with overall vehicle requirements.

Comment: As the top image shows, there is a cavity whose diameter decreases per the cone shapes, including the transitions to the two different cones in the Forward Segment, even with its Star Geometry Grain. With all of this, I would challenge the image above of the view from the nozzle upwards. One would see only the “walls” of the 3 different cones, and not be able to see the Star Geometry Grain. I would believe that the only way to see that would be to take off the Nose Cap/Frustrum.

Comment: The image referenced in the last three comments is at the top as a question revision, since that was the only way I could figure to get it inserted.

Comment: @DaveS there's a picture I saved from an ATK presentation that I think agrees with your 2nd comment https://i.imgur.com/hv8U0iG.png I don't think you're right in your comment about not being able to see the star though.  We need a photo though.